# How to write data to a file for loading into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, perl

I am having some sort of I/O bottleneck inserting parsed data into a MySQL database. So instead of parsing the file and inserting each record into the database individually, I would like to write the records to a file (like a CSV) and then I can load the file into the database manually.

How can I approach this using Perl? Below is the code that currently inserts the data into the database, but I would like to write the data to a file instead, in a format that makes inserting it into MySQL later as painless as possible.

```
#INSERT INTO ANNOUNCE TABLE
foreach my $au (@ANNOUNCED) {

    my $val=$au->[0];
    my $IP = $prefix->ip();
    my $subnetmask = $prefix->mask();


    $Announce_update->execute($IP,$subnetmask,$UpdateKey);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load data from an external file, MySQL provides the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command. `LOAD DATA INFILE` is fairly flexible when it comes to input file formats, allowing you to specify the delimiter, EOL character, whether fields are quoted, etc. It works great in concert with [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm), which you can use to output a delimited file containing your data.

First, write your data to a file:

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ eol => "\n" }) or die Text::CSV->error_diag();

my $infile = "/path/to/file";
open my $fh, ">", $infile or die $!;

for my $i (0..$#ANNOUNCED)
{
   # Don't end last line with '\n' or we'll get a garbage row when we load
   # to the database
   $csv->eol(undef) if $i == $#ANNOUNCED;

   # Generate the data to insert for this row

   # Write to file
   $csv->print($fh, [ $IP, $subnetmask, $UpdateKey ]);
}

# Close file handle to flush the buffer
close $fh;
```

Note that you must close the file handle after writing to it or MySQL may not get all of the data.

Next, load the file:

```
my $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$infile' INTO TABLE table
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";

eval {
   # $dbh is an already open database handle
   my $rows_inserted = $dbh->do($query);
};
die $@ if $@;
```

The `LOCAL` keyword affects whether the file is located on the MySQL server or not. If you're loading to a database located on localhost, you can leave off the `LOCAL` keyword, counter-intuitive as that may sound (with `LOCAL`, the client sends a copy of the file to the server's temporary directory and the server reads it from there, so it is local to the server). Without the `LOCAL` keyword, the file must be readable to all (i.e. permissions of at least `0644` on *nix, since you also have to write to it). MySQL will also look in different places for relative paths depending on whether `LOCAL` is used or not; see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for details.

The above query assumes that your table only has three columns. If it has more, you need to specify which columns you're inserting data for, *in the order the appear in the CSV*, e.g.:

```
my $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$infile' INTO TABLE table
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
             (ip, subnetmask, updatekey)";
```

### Compound inserts

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is by far the fastest method if you're inserting a large number of rows at once. For smaller inserts, however, the additional I/O overhead of writing to and reading from a temporary file (especially if you use the `LOCAL` option) makes it slower than using compound inserts like this one:

```
# Inserts 3 rows at once
INSERT INTO table VALUES (foo, foo, foo), (bar, bar, bar), (baz, baz, baz)
```

There is a magic number of rows for which `LOAD DATA INFILE` becomes faster than compound inserts. For my database and application, I did some profiling and found that this number was on the order of 100, but it is almost certainly different for you. I wrote a function to select the most efficient method depending on the number of rows of data to be inserted:

```
sub insert_rows {
    my $data = shift; # Reference to an AoA

    my $num_rows = $#{ $data };

    if ($num_rows < 100) {
        # Generate compound insert statement
    }
    else {
        # LOAD DATA INFILE
    }
}
```

Be aware that the default value of [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is only 1MB in MySQL 5.7. If your compound insert statement exceeds this, you will get a `Packet too large` error and the insert will fail. You can adjust this up to a maximum of 1GB, but by that point you will have probably reached the threshold where `LOAD DATA INFILE` is more efficient anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed explanation and time taken to edit my question. There are somethings i do not understand like the changes you made to my script in your answer. I will upload my whole script for you to see and may delete later. I also don't understand this line : 
for my $i (0..$#ANNOUNCED).

Comment: So since i have like 10000 files which i am to parse, what i am doing is inserting the data to the database after record(block) in a particular file. It takes about 5 minutes for just 1 file to complete parsing and insertion. But then i thought, instead of inserting to the database, i will just write the parsed data into a csv or something then do the LOAD DATA INFILE as you suggested.

Comment: @iseesharp I merely omitted the steps you take to set `$IP`, `$subnetmask`, and `$UpdateKey`, to avoid cluttering the answer. You obviously need to add those steps in to get your values.

Comment: @iseesharp `for my $i (0..$#ANNOUNCED)` loops through the `@ANNOUNCED` array, setting the variable `$i` to the current array index. To access the current element inside the loop, use `$ANNOUNCED[$i]`. This is necessary because you don't want the last line in the file to end with `\n` or MySQL will load a garbage row.

Answer (score 1):

Probably using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) will make your life easier at this point. Install that module if it is not already on your system and then add this line to your script:

```
use Text::CSV ;
```

Comment out the database insertion bits in your code:

```
 # $dbh->prepare("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;")->execute();
 # $Announce_update->execute($IP,$subnetmask,$UpdateKey);
```

and then try grabbing the data you want:

```
 my @csvdata = ($IP,$subnetmask,$UpdateKey); # assuming data is in these vars 
                                              # and they aren't references used 
                                              # by $Announce_update somehow
```

then write it out to the CSV files somewhere (cribbed from the documentation) which you will load "manually" (by which I assume you mean using the MySQL console or CLI tool).

```
  my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  
  open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "csvdata.csv" or die ;
  $csv->print ($fh, $_) for @csvdata;
```

Hope this helps - though it is a bit short on hand holding.  Even if it does work I'm not sure you are making your life easier by doing this ;-)

Comment: Of course if you have the data **already** in another file is might be quicker/easier to just grab it from there ... though I can see why you might want to keep the workflow mostly the same while you investigate your bottleneck.  Why not get help for the real problem while you're at it? Could the bottleneck be in the insertion/update script itself?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am presently looking into the Text::CSV as you adviced and also following on what ThisSuitIsBlackNot said in his answer though i am to fully comprehend.